# How to make Materialize tap-target rectangular in shape

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am using materialize-css and I want to make tape target area rectangular how is that achievable?

Currently My Tap-target area looks like this and my content are hidden:-
[image]

My html code goes like this:-

```html
<div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 100px; right: 24px;">
    <a id="menu" class="btn btn-floating btn-large cyan">
        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
    </a>
</div>

<!-- Tap Target Structure -->
<div class="tap-target cyan" data-target="menu">
    <div class="tap-target-content white-text">
        <h5>Holiday List</h5>
        <p class="white-text" style="font-size:120%;">
            <b>
                Sat Aug 01 Bakri Id<br>
                Mon Aug 03 Raksha Bandhan<br>
                Wed Aug 12 Janamasthami<br>
                Sat Aug 15 Independence Day<br>
                Fri Oct 02 Gandhi Jayanti<br>
                Mon Oct 26 Dusshera<br>
                Sat Nov 14 Diwali<br>
                Mon Nov 16 Bhai Duj<br>
                Fri Dec 25 Christmas Day
            </b>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.tap-target {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Inspect the element, look at the styles that are applied and override as you need - anything circular is likely to have `border-radius:50%`.

In some cases you may need to use `!important`:

```
.tap-target {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want all elements with a tap-target class to be square, you could add an id to that element and style the id. Based on how css prioritizes more specific selectors, it also reduces the chance you need to use !important, which is good to avoid where possible.

Comment: In this case, we don't need `!important` - and adding IDs for extra specificity is not needed. I only mentioned it because a lot of base materialize styles need !important to override - for instance, text input color. (In this case, it would be totally impractical to add IDs to every input, and then reference these in your css file individually). So I just mentioned it because a lot of newcomers to Materialize still have problems with overriding, even when shown the correct classes. https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/rNxjKwV